# how do you do nested objects in graphql - i'm using appsync and dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync

I have the following object and I want to create a schema for it that handles nested objects - what's the best way using graphql:

```
    {
        "type": "product",
        "id": "411e2a2b-37e8-421e-adb8-2e038751d263",
        "name": "Hazel",
        "slug": "hazel",
        "sku": "ENGINEERED3",
        "manage_stock": false,
        "description": "Abstract, sculptural, refined and edgy with a modern twist. Its symmetrical, spoked structure generates a clever geometric presence, which works well in a contemporary environment..",
        "price": [
            {
                "amount": 11200,
                "currency": "AUD",
                "includes_tax": true
            }
        ],
        "status": "live",
        "commodity_type": "physical",
        "meta": {
            "timestamps": {
                "created_at": "2019-05-09T13:30:10+00:00",
                "updated_at": "2019-05-09T13:45:11+00:00"
            },
            "display_price": {
                "with_tax": {
                    "amount": 11200,
                    "currency": "AUD",
                    "formatted": "$112.00"
                },
                "without_tax": {
                    "amount": 11200,
                    "currency": "AUD",
                    "formatted": "$112.00"
                }
            },
            "stock": {
                "level": 0,
                "availability": "out-stock"
            }
        }
    }
```

It seems as though graphql wants a separate type per nested object - is that true?

Comment: true - typically for `id`-identified types - only one object/type here (with complex properties only - use fragments for them?) - any graphql experience?

Comment: In this case, you'd still probably want to define your nested as their own type objects. You can use things like interfaces or fragments to maximize code re-use, but this will be dependent on your use case. So for this object, you'd have 5 simple types defined along with the parent object, eg  `priceInfo`, `productMetadata`, `timestamps`, `displayPrice`, `stockInfo`. Not all types need to have an `id` defined on it, as these nested items won't be queried directly.

Comment: I agree with the above comments about defining types. but if you want to be real generic... you could try defining the nested stuff as "AWSJSON" in your schema and see if that gets you where you want to be while you define types - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/scalars.html#awsjson